# сериализация, метод PATCH

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

Изучаю DRF и попытался создать вложенный сериализатор.
`.create()` работает успешно.

`.update()` атрибуты `group` редактируются успешно, но попытки изменить id провалены.
Как я понял `group_data.get('id')` передает `None`, причина мне непонятна.
пример PATCH-запроса:

```
{
    "text": "Тестовый пост_2_7",
    "group": {"id": 2}

}
```

при попытке передавать id в формате: {"group": 2} ошибка.

```
{
    "group": {
        "non_field_errors": [
            "Invalid data. Expected a dictionary, but got int."
        ]
    }
}
```

```
class GroupSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Group
        fields = ('id', 'title', 'slug', 'description')


class PostCreateSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    author = serializers.SlugRelatedField(
        slug_field='username', read_only=True
    )
    group = GroupSerializer(required=False)

    def create(self, validated_data):
        """
        Тестовый метод для проверки работы вложенного сериализатора.
        """
        group_data = validated_data.pop('group')
        group = Group.objects.create(**group_data)
        post = Post.objects.create(**validated_data, group=group)
        return post

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        """
        Тестовый метод для проверки обновления вложенного сериализатора.
        """
        if validated_data.get('group') is None:
            return super().update(instance, validated_data)
        group_data = validated_data.pop('group')
        if group_data.get('id'):
            group_id = group_data.get('id')
            group = Group.objects.get(id=group_id)
            instance.group = group
            instance.save()
            return super().update(instance, validated_data)
        """
        нерешенная проблема:
        меняются атрибуты group, но попытки изменить id провалены.
        """

        group = instance.group
        group.title = group_data.get('title', group.title)
        group.slug = group_data.get('slug', group.slug)
        group.description = group_data.get('description', group.description)
        group.save()
        return super().update(instance, validated_data)
```

Заранее благодарю за помощь!

Answer (score 0):

Ответ найден, был изменен .get_serializer_class() во вьюсете